# Is WinGetUI necessary for using WinGet?

Tags: winget

I use Chocolatey for doing some installations. I've decided I'd also add WinGet to my machine. During the process of installing WinGet it also suggested I install WinGetUI. I thought that meant WinGetUI was necessary for the functioning of WinGet, so I went ahead and installed WinGetUI as well.

Now, WinGetUI pops up notifications on a regular and frequent basis, informing me that there's so many updates I could apply. That's OK, but not as often as WinGetUI does this. I'd like to know if WinGetUI is necessary for the functioning of WinGet?

Comment: Nope. You can stop it from starting when the computer boots with (for example) https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns (note that [the WinGetUI github](https://github.com/marticliment/WingetUI) says: "Disclaimer: This project has no connection with Winget, Chocolatey or Scoop — it's completely unofficial. ")

Comment: Oh, that's irritating. Thank you, I'll get rid of it.

Comment: Did my answer help @Rod?

Answer (score 1):

No. WinGet is a package manager. Package managers normally don't require GUI, in case something goes wrong with your system and you can't access system's interface to uninstall faulty app(s). Thus they're programmed for CLI by default and the Windows ones also follow this standard.

GUI apps are extras that help less experienced users or often they're more comfortable to use than CLI. On Linux you can also find a bunch of more advanced CLI apps that draw traversable interfaces in the console (TUIs).

As for the notifications in WingetUI, you can always disable them:

1. Click on upper right vertical three dots icon (kebab menu).
2. Choose `WingetUI settings`.
3. Choose `Notification bar options`.
4. Disable notifications when updates are available.

Comment: I don't think its actually part of the default install either - I've been running winget  on windows 11 (where I think its stock) and 10 (where its installed) and neither has/had the ui installed

Comment: It's also stock on newer Windows 10 I'm pretty sure. No clue where author got that install from.

Comment: WingetUI (i am the dev) is a third party utility, and is not required to be able to run Winget. It only provides a graphical interface for winget, scoop and chocolatey (and for others in the future)